# About the mechanism of using fgets() and stdin together

Tags: c, stdin, fgets

I would like to have a better understanding of using `fgets()` and `stdin`.
The following is my code:

```
int main()
{
    char inputBuff[6];
    while(fgets(inputBuff, 6, stdin))
    {
        printf("%s", inputBuff);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Let's say my input is `aaaabbbb` and I press Enter. By using a loopcount, I understand that actually the loop will run twice (including the one I input `aaaabbbb`) before my next input.

**Loop 1:** After I have typed in the characters, `aaaabbbb\n` will be stored in the buffer of `stdin` file stream. And `fgets()` is going to retrieve a specific number of data from the file stream and put them in `inputBuff`. In this case, it will retrieve 5 (6 - 1) characters at a time. So that when `fgets()` has already run once, `inputBuff` will store `aaaab`, and then be printed.

**Loop 2:** Then, since `bbb\n` are left in the file stream, `fgets()` will execute for the second time so that `inputBuff` contains `bbb\n`, and then be printed.

**Loop 3:** The program will ask for my input (the 2nd time) as the file stream has reached the end (`EOF`).

**Question:** It seems that `fgets()` will only ask for my keyboard input after `stdin` stream has no data left in buffer (`EOF`). I am just wondering why couldn't I use keyboard to input anything in loop 2, and `fgets()` just keep on retrieving 5 characters from `stdin` stream and left the excess data in the file stream for next time retrieval. Do I have any misunderstanding about `stdin` or `fgets()`? Thank you for your time!

Comment: It isn't quite clear at what point reality diverges from your expectations. Can you show input that produces unexpected output?

Comment: From the Fine Manual: `fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream  and
       stores  them  into  the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after an
       EOF or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the  buffer.
       A '\0' is stored after the last character in the buffer.`

Comment: Were you expecting the `"bbb\n"` to be thrown away, and fresh input requested? If so, how could a program read a line when its length was unknown beforehand?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with _"I am just wondering why couldnt I use keyboard to input anything in loop 2, and fgets() just keep on retrieving 5 characters from stdin stream..."_? Did you want to interject something in the middle of the previous string (before the `bbb\n`), or have `fgets` read past the newline, or what?

Comment: Sorry guys, I had some coding tasks to do so I am not able to reply your comments at once. Sorry for replying so late.

@n.m.  No, I didnt receive any unexpected outputs. Just want to know why  'sometimes' I am not asked to input sth whenever fgets() is called.

Comment: @joop Thx for quoting the linux manual. "A '\0' is stored after the last character in the buffer." I didnt aware of this. Thx for reminding me.

Comment: @WeatherVane Well, I expected "bbb\n" to be kept and fresh input will be requested also. The input will be appended to "bbb\n".

Comment: @ilkkachu Sorry for my poor english. I just want to know why sometimes I am not asked to input sth whenever fgets() is called. Under this circumstance, only when the stdin stream reaches an end, I am asked to use my keyboard to input things.

Comment: The function `fgets` reads to the end of the line, or until the buffer is full. The first call stops because the buffer is full. The second call stops when the end of line is reached. if `fgets` had waited for more input from you, it could have read *two* lines, but it doesn't do that. It only reads one line. It didn't need any more input because it already has enough.

Comment: @WeatherVane "it could have read two lines, but it doesn't do that. It only reads one line. " I finally understand why I was not asked to input anything in loop 2. Thx so much for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of your program is somewhat more subtle than you expect:

`fgets(inputBuff, 6, stdin)` reads at most 5 bytes from `stdin` and stops reading when it gets a newline character, which is stored into the destination array.

Hence as you correctly diagnose, the first call reads the 5 bytes `aaab` and prints them and the second call reads 4 bytes `bbb\n` and prints them, then the third call gets an empty input stream and waits for user input.

The tricky part is how `stdin` gets input from the user, also known as console input.

Both console input and `stdin` are usually line buffered by default, so you can type a complete line of input regardless of the size of the buffer passed to `fgets()`.  Yet if you can set `stdin` as unbuffered and console input as uncooked, the first `fgets()` would indeed read the first 5 bytes as soon as you type them.

Console input is an intricate subject. Here is an in depth article about its inner workings: https://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/

Comment: Very useful and detailed information! Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

`fgets()` does only read until either `'\n'` or `EOF`. Everything after that will be left in `stdin` and therefore be read when you call `fgets()` again. You can however remove the excess chars from `stdin` by for example using `getc()` until you reach `'\0'`. You might want to look at the manpages for that.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is there in manual page of `fgets()` whatever you are asking. Just need to read it properly, It says

> `char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);`
>
> fgets() reads in at most **one less** than sizecharacters
>   from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading
>   stops after an **EOF or a newline.** If a newline is read, it is
>   stored into the buffer. A terminating null byte (aq\0aq) is stored
>   after the last character in the buffer.

If input is `aaaabbbb` and in `fgets()` second argument you specified size as `6` i.e it will read one less `5` character and terminating `\0` will be added so first time `inputBuff` holds `aaaab` and since still `EOF` or `\n` didn't occur so next time `inputBuff` holds `bbb\n` as new line also get stored at last.

Also you should check the return type of `fgets()` and check if `\n` occurs then break the loop. For e.g

```
char *ptr = NULL;

while( (ptr = fgets(inputBuff, 6, stdin))!= NULL){
          if(*ptr == '\n')
                   break;
          printf("%s", inputBuff);
}
```

Comment: Thx for reminding me that I need to add a condition in order to break the loop.

"fgets() reads in at most one less than sizecharacters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading stops after an EOF or a newline."

Does it mean that actually fgets() haven't finished its "first" reading input process after storing "aaaab" in the buffer?

Just after "bbb\n" is read, fgets() starts the second request for user's input.

If so, why the following printf() can still be executed even fgets() has not stopped reading(reaching EOF or newline char)?

Comment: @GarethLam `fgets` didn't finish reading the *entire* line, but it did read a *part* of the line and *has* stopped at this point. You can `printf` the part read so far. Nex time, it will start reading from where it has left off. If the line is longer than 5 characters, then your program cannot be in a state when the entirety the line is read and ready to be printed, because there's simply no space to hold the entire line. The best it can do, and indeed does, is reading longer lines piece by piece.

Comment: @n.m. It seems that I dont have a good understanding of fgets() and stdin. Didnt know I need to wait after the entire line is read by fgets() to input new characters. Thank you for your comments. I really have more in-depth understanding in these 2 functions.